# How to attach handler for JFileChooser buttons inside custom JFrame in Java

Tags: java, swing, singleton, jfilechooser

I have a singleton pattern class called MyFileChooser which adapts if JFileChooser is `FILES_ONLY` or `DIRECTORIES_ONLY` according to constructor parameter.

I wish to have the JFileChooser inside JFrame, so I can add additional information above and below JFileChooser frame, so the structure will look:

```
JFrame
 | JLabel
 | JFileChooser
 | JLabel
// end of JFrame
```

---

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class MyFileChooser {
    private JFrame frame;
    private boolean isFilesOnly;
    private static final MyFileChooser instance_files = new MyFileChooser( true );
    private static final MyFileChooser instance_dirs = new MyFileChooser( false );

    private JFileChooser dynamicChooser;

    private MyFileChooser( boolean filesOnly ) {
        this.frame = new JFrame();
        this.isFilesOnly = filesOnly;
        this.dynamicChooser = new JFileChooser();
        this.frameSetup();
        this.chooserSetup();
    }

    public MyFileChooser getInstance( boolean filesOnly ) {
        if ( filesOnly ) {
            return MyFileChooser.instance_files;
        } else {
            return MyFileChooser.instance_dirs;
        }
    }

    public void frameSetup() {
        // jframe and labels setup code
        this.frame.getContentPane().add( this.dynamicChooser );
    }

    public void chooserSetup() {
        if ( this.isFilesOnly ) {
            this.dynamicChooser.setFileSelectionMode( JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY );
        } else {
            this.dynamicChooser.setFileSelectionMode( JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY );
        }
        this.dynamicChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        this.dynamicChooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.CUSTOM_DIALOG);
    }
```

The issue is that I dont know how to attach handler for "Close" and "Open" buttons of JFileChooser. The only thing I've found is:

```
public void handleSelectedFiles() {
   int returnVal = this.dynamicChooser.showDialog(this.frame, "Open");
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File[] files = this.dynamicChooser.getSelectedFiles();
            // do something
        }
}
```

But, it opens both instances if this method is called and even without JFrame wrap & JLabels from required structure.
So my question is how can I get button of "Open" and "Close" from JFileChooser to attach handler (**different for instances**) or how to handle the selected files by other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is here

```
int returnVal = this.dynamicChooser.showDialog(this.frame, "Open");
```

It's call the underlying `JFileChooser`'s `showDialog` method, so it's constructing its own window, ignoring yours

A better solution is create a `JDialog` on demand and use it to container your file chooser and other controls

Something a little more like...

```
public class MyFileChooser {

    private final boolean isFilesOnly;
    private static final MyFileChooser INSTANCE_FILES = new MyFileChooser(true);
    private static final MyFileChooser INSTANCE_DIRS = new MyFileChooser(false);

    private final JFileChooser dynamicChooser;

    private MyFileChooser(boolean filesOnly) {
        this.isFilesOnly = filesOnly;
        this.dynamicChooser = new JFileChooser();
        dynamicChooser.setControlButtonsAreShown(false);
        this.chooserSetup();
    }

    public MyFileChooser getInstance(boolean filesOnly) {
        if (filesOnly) {
            return MyFileChooser.INSTANCE_FILES;
        } else {
            return MyFileChooser.INSTANCE_DIRS;
        }
    }

    public void frameSetup(Container parent) {
        // jframe setup code
        parent.add(this.dynamicChooser);
    }

    public void chooserSetup() {
        if (this.isFilesOnly) {
            this.dynamicChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        } else {
            this.dynamicChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        }
        this.dynamicChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        this.dynamicChooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.CUSTOM_DIALOG);
    }
    
    public File[] showOpenDialog(Component parent, String title) {
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog(parent == null ? null : SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(parent), title);
        dialog.setModal(true);
        frameSetup(dialog);
        
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
        
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        
        return dynamicChooser.getSelectedFiles();
    }
}
```

The intention is to mimic the actions of `showDialog` from `JFileChooser`.  In this example, I've hidden the "normal" control buttons, as I assume you'll be providing your own, through which you can change the return file

Now, if you still want to use the standard button controls, you can attach an `ActionListener` to the `JFileChooser`

```
dynamicChooser.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
        //...
    }
});
```

When I was testing, the Cancel button return `CancelSelection` and Choose button return `ApproveSelection`

Now, because my example uses a dynamic dialog, you may need to create a dynamic `ActionListener` which can control the dialog, because you don't want to keep adding `ActionListener`s to the `FileChooser` without removing them, something like...

```
public File[] showOpenDialog(Component parent, String title) {
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog(parent == null ? null : SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(parent), title);
    dialog.setModal(true);
    frameSetup(dialog);

    ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
            //..
            dialog.dispose();
        }
    };
    dynamicChooser.addActionListener(listener);

    dialog.pack();
    dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(parent);

    dialog.setVisible(true);
    dynamicChooser.removeActionListener(listener);

    return dynamicChooser.getSelectedFiles();
}
```

as an example

## Observation

Because I know someone will kick me to curb if I don't...

Sington's in Java are tricky things and there are countless threads on the subject, however, it's generally accepted that the best approach (now) is to use a `enum`, which solves all the synchronisation issues of old

So, instead, you might consider using something like..

```
public static enum MyFileChooser {

    INSTANCE_FILES(true),
    INSTANCE_DIRS(false);

    private final boolean isFilesOnly;

    private final JFileChooser dynamicChooser;

    private MyFileChooser(boolean filesOnly) {
        this.isFilesOnly = filesOnly;
        this.dynamicChooser = new JFileChooser();
        //dynamicChooser.setControlButtonsAreShown(false);
        this.chooserSetup();
    }

    public void frameSetup(Container parent) {
        // jframe setup code
        parent.add(this.dynamicChooser);
    }

    public void chooserSetup() {
        if (this.isFilesOnly) {
            this.dynamicChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        } else {
            this.dynamicChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        }
        this.dynamicChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        this.dynamicChooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.CUSTOM_DIALOG);
    }

    public File[] showOpenDialog(Component parent, String title) {
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog(parent == null ? (JDialog)null : SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(parent), title);
        dialog.setModal(true);
        frameSetup(dialog);

        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
                //..
                dialog.dispose();
            }
        };
        dynamicChooser.addActionListener(listener);

        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(parent);

        dialog.setVisible(true);
        dynamicChooser.removeActionListener(listener);

        return dynamicChooser.getSelectedFiles();
    }
}
```

Which you can call simply using something like...

```
File[] files = MyFileChooser.INSTANCE_FILES.showOpenDialog(null, "Open");
```

*"I've mentioned I wish to have JLabels between chooser,"*

I had thought that laying out comments was just a matter of reading any one of the thousands of examples which are available, apparently I was mistaken

So, a simple update to the `frameSetup` method solves that issue...

```
public void frameSetup(Container parent) {
    // jframe setup code
    parent.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    parent.add(new JLabel("I'm on top"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    parent.add(this.dynamicChooser);
    parent.add(new JLabel("I'm on bottom"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

[image: Simple Layout]

Have a look at [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more details

To make sure it works correctly, I updated the `showOpenDialog` method to use

```
frameSetup(dialog.getContentPane());
```

instead of just passing the instance of the `JDialog`, this ensures that we're effecting the correct container

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm forget to mention that I wish to use default buttons (simple open-get files, close hide frame). However, you have updated :) Unfortunatelly I can not test this because it throws me error "reference to JDialog is ambigous" when I try to compile the class.

Comment: Change `parent == null ? null : ...` to `parent == null ? (JDialog)null : ...`

Comment: This above solved the ambigous issue. Honestly, I think that enum solution is excellent, but however, it does not show the JFrame and requested JLabels in my project, just the JFileChooser window.

Comment: That's because your example code didn't include any additional components.  Try applying a `BorderLayout` to the `container` passed to `frameSetup` and then adding components to the `NORTH` and `SOUTH` positions

Comment: I've mentioned I wish to have JLabels between chooser, where they are initialized inside `frameSetup` method. I just 'fixed' it, but the JFileChooser is not inside JFrame but they're separated, any idea where I did mistake? (Also closing chooser dont close JFrame)

Comment: Since my example code doesn't have a JFrame, I have no idea what you're doing wrong, you'll have a lot of issues trying to solve this with a JFrame. The "other" part of your question comes down to a simple layout issue, which is easily resolved through any number of layout tutorials and examples, the example I've provided gets you to that point, can't spoil all the fun for you ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, it now works as excepted. I was a bit confused, because I didn't realize that you replaced JFrame for JDialog in your example and I was trying to put window to container. It was 3.00 AM I apologize.

Comment: Ah, late night coding, what joy ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134841/discussion-between-t4dohx-and-madprogrammer).

Comment: Could you please help me in chat? :/